# create thread , do something, kill thread - all inside loop [JAVA]

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, coding-style

I'm very new to threads. I need to implement such method, which will create 2 threads, do something and then kill them - everything inside the for loop.

Main purpose : I need to be SURE that threads will work parallel with the same "i" value from for loop. That's why I do not declare for loop inside every thread. (which one finish first I do not care)

My vision

```
          public void threadsJob() throws Exception{
          for(int i = 1; i<1000 ; i++) {
          **final** int j = i;
          Thread t1= new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                     foo(j);
                }     
           }
      );

          Thread t2= new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                     bar(j);
                }     
           }
      );

      t1.start();
      t2.start();

      t1.join();
      t2.join();
}}
```

My question : how horrible is that code? what should be changed ? Also I prefer to keep code quite simple. However, Im not sure if above code is suitable example :)

Comment: Depending on what foo and bar actually do it's quite likely that making new threads takes long than it would have to just do the work serially.  Use a thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Execute two Runnables that perform your work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Then shutdown and awaitTermination on the ExecutorService.